# Formulario dinámico de factura

Tags: javascript, php, html

tengo un formulario para crear una factura que permite generar líneas dinámicamente. El problema que tengo es que el resto del formulario de crear factura ya funciona correctamente (Lo envío a través de POST y todo correcto), pero al enviar el formulario, las líneas no se envían (El formulario es el que viene en Bootstrap como plantilla). ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo para que las lineas de la factura se envíen junto con el formulario? Gracias.

Las lineas de la factura (Obviamente por encima de todo el formulario está la etiqueta de `<form>`)

```
<div class="invoice-detail-items">
     <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered item-table">
                 <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class=""></th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th class="">Cantidad</th>
                            <th class="">Precio</th>
                            <th class="text-right">Base</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Mostrar</th>
                        </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="delete-item-row">
                                <ul class="table-controls">
                                     <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Delete"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="15" y1="9" x2="9" y2="15"></line><line x1="9" y1="9" x2="15" y2="15"></line></svg></a>
                                      </li>
                               </ul>
                           </td>
                           <td class="description"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Descripción" name="descripcion"> </td>
                            <td class="text-right qty"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Cantidad" name="cantidad"></td>
                            <td class="rate"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Precio" name="precio">
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right amount"><span class="editable-amount"><span class="currency"></span> <span class="amount">100.00</span>
                            </td>
                             <td class="text-center tax">                                               
                                  <div class="n-chk">
                                      <label class="new-control new-checkbox new-checkbox-text checkbox-primary" style="height: 18px; margin: 0 auto;">
                                      <input type="checkbox" checked class="new-control-input" name="mostrar">
                                      <span class="new-control-indicator"></span><span class="new-chk-content">Mostrar en factura</span>
                                        </label>
                                  </div>
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                      </tbody>
                 </table>
           </div>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary additem btn-sm">Añadir Linea</button>
       </div>
```

Por si hace falta, este es el Javascript que añade la linea:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('additem')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('dfdf')

  getTableElement = document.querySelector('.item-table');
  currentIndex = getTableElement.rows.length;

  $html = '<tr>'+
  '<td class="delete-item-row">'+
      '<ul class="table-controls">'+
          '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete-item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Delete"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="15" y1="9" x2="9" y2="15"></line><line x1="9" y1="9" x2="15" y2="15"></line></svg></a></li>'+
      '</ul>'+
    '</td>'+
    '<td class="description"><input type="text" class="form-control  form-control-sm" placeholder="Descripción" name="descripcion"> </textarea></td>'+
    '<td class="rate">'+
        '<input type="text" class="form-control  form-control-sm" placeholder="Precio" name="precio">'+
   ' </td>'+
    '<td class="text-right qty"><input type="text" class="form-control  form-control-sm" placeholder="Cantidad" name="cantidad"></td>'+
    '<td class="text-right amount"><span class="editable-amount"><span class="currency">$</span> <span class="amount">0.00</span></td>'+
    '<td class="text-center tax">'+
        '<div class="n-chk">'+
            '<label class="new-control new-checkbox new-checkbox-text checkbox-primary" style="height: 18px; margin: 0 auto;">'+
              '<input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input" name="mostrar">'+
              '<span class="new-control-indicator"></span><span class="new-chk-content" >Mostrar</span>'+
           ' </label>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</td>'+
    '</tr>';

  $(".item-table tbody").append($html);
  deleteItemRow();

})
```

Y este es el botón de envio:

```
<div class="col-xl-12 col-md-4">
     <button class="btn btn-success btn-download">Guardar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Si eso lo envias con POST entiendo que usas un botón SUBMIT, y no veo que uses en ningún input el atributo **name=** que es necesario en este caso (si es así como mandas el formulario, pues no lo indicas de forma clara en la pregunta)

Comment: Vale, ese botón no es del tipo **submit**, por lo tanto debes mostrarnos el javascript que lee el evento de pulsación sobre el para ver que hace y como recoge los datos para luego reenviarlos por POST (seguramente mediante ajax), pues no lo vemos y a ciegas no vamos a dar con una respuesta certera.

Comment: Vale, he añadido el atributo name tanto al javascript como al html (Es cierto que no estaban nombrados y por eso no se enviaban). Respondiendo a masterguru si, ese botón es el que envía el form y de hecho acabo de comprobarlo con varias líneas y ya funciona correctamente y se mandan todas las líneas por POST, el único problema es que se mandan con el mismo nombre, por lo que ahora necesito identificar cada linea con un numerador o algo así, para luego poder recogerlas todas en PHP

Comment: Ahora has puesto los name, pero de forma única, es decir, si tienes varias líneas tan solo va a enviar o bien la primera o bien la última (ahora no recuerdo cual, pero solo una de ellas).   Cuando esto sucede lo que se hace es indicar en el atributo **name=** que se trata de un array de datos, y se indica con un corchete al final del nombre puesto en _name_ de este modo:  `name="cantidad[]"`, y sabiendo eso, al recuperar la variable en PHP, debes tener en cuenta que es un array y tratarlo como tal, y no como un valor único.

Comment: Ok, entiendo la lógica, lo que no es es como ejecutarlo, porque, ¿Como aumento el valor del array en cada linea añadida? ¿Te importaría ponerme un ejemplo y ya te lo acepto como respuesta? 

Gracias

Comment: Al usar **name="cantidad[]"** debes recogerlo en PHP al igual que los demás. De forma simple seria `$cantidad = $_POST['cantidad']`, pero luego, para tratarlo en PHP, debes recorrerlo en un bucle parecido a esto: `foreach ($cantidad as $index=>$dato) { $cantidad_real = $dato; $descripcion_real = $_POST["descripcion][$index]; etc.. }` y dentro de ese bucle agregas las lineas en la base de datos. Fíjate que aprovechamos la variable $index que nos correlaciona todos los **name** de cada linea correctamente en las otras variables de array recibidas en cada linea.

Comment: Me interesa más que lo entiendas y quieras comprender y solucionar por ti mismo que darte una respuesta completa que sea copiar y pegar y a otra cosa, je.  En determinadas preguntas me gusta más dar la caña que el pez :-)

Comment: Jaja, en realidad es así como se aprende, así que sin problema. Ya casi lo tengo así que gracias

Comment: Cuando lo tengas solucionado (y espero que llegues a ello con mis comentarios) tu mismo puedes postear la respuesta que te ha funcionado y en 48 horas podrás aceptarla y así le darás más visibilidad y la comunidad lo sabrá y la pregunta no quedará eternamente pendiente.